# lsof for a specific process?

Tags: linux, command-line, process

There's a `bzip2` process running in the background and I have no idea where it came from. It's eating up a lot of resources. Can I do a reverse `lsof` to see which files are being accessed by this process?

I've suspended the process for the time being.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I'm not sure why that'd be a "reverse `lsof`" -- `lsof` does exactly that. You can pass it the `-p` flag to specify which PIDs to include/exclude in the results:

```
$ lsof -p $(pidof bzip2)
```

Comment: Reverse from `lsof /path/to/file` (which I guess is the mode of operation Pieter is used to).

Comment: Note that if you have existing filters to `lsof`, you can use `-a` to AND them instead of ORing them: `lsof -a -i TCP -p 12345`.

Answer (score 7):

In the `/proc/` directory you can find details of the running processes, in separate directories, by their PID. Their file descriptors are enumerated in the `fd/` sub-directory:

```
ls -l /proc/$(pidof -s bzip2)/fd/
```